# how to sort lines of file.txt according to str len - php

Tags: php

i want to sort a file.txt according to string len

sample file.txt :

```
wew
12dde
12swsw
11
swsw
a
```

ofter sort file sorted.txt :

```
a
11
wew
swsw
12dde
12swsw
```

Comment: http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/array-usort.php

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = <<<EOT
wew
12dde
12swsw
11
swsw
a
EOT;

$array = explode("\n", $string);

usort($array, function($a, $b) { return strlen($a) - strlen($b); });

var_dump($array);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "11"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "wew"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "swsw"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "12dde"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "12swsw"
}
```

Comment: tanX , how can i echo this parametrs in page ?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php
function lensort($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) - strlen($b);
}

$path1 = '/root/oldfile.txt';
$path2 = '/root/newfile.txt';
file_put_contents($path2, usort(file($path1), 'lensort'));
```